# jQuery: insertAfter() doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this function to create a hint button after the input box.

```
function hint_draw() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#formIDHere input[name='name[]']");
    for(i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement("a");
        button.innerHTML = "<img src='image/hint.jpg' width='32' height='32'></img>";
        button.href = "javascript:hint("+ i +")";
        $(button).insertAfter(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

This code works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox. Why?

EDIT: Really, this script works fine.
Maybe I have problems with the other things.
The best answer is [jQuery: insertAfter() doesn't work on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240595/jquery-insertafter-doesnt-work-on-firefox#comment52362795_32240595) but it's a comment so I can't accept it.
Bye!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfj3cs08/1/ - looks fine

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does it not insert the button, the button inserts but doesn't do anything?

Comment: Maybe the invalid `</img>` tag is confusing Firefox.

Comment: It should be `$("#formIDHere input[name='name[]']").after(function(i){
        return '<a href="javascript:hint('+i+')"><img src="image/hint.jpg" width="32" height="32"></a>'
    });` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfj3cs08/5/

Comment: Here's a versionof @ArunPJohny's fiddle that shows that `hint(i)` works. http://jsfiddle.net/hfj3cs08/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hfj3cs08/8/

Comment: @KhanhHuynhTran  it's working fine dude you might have problem with the other thing if you still getting this not working

Comment: Thank you @Himesh Aadeshara, i still getting this not working. Try my live example here http://gg.gg/listenhear just view source :D

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hfj3cs08/6/ this fiddle works fine.

May be your firefox version is not supporting the  tag.

Change the button.innerHTML like the following

```
button.innerHTML = "<img src='image/hint.jpg' width='32' height='32'/>";
```